# change status of a table based on another table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using MYSQL and want a status update in my primary table based on the foreign table.  I have listed my problem below

[image]

I want that when the status of all the records with the same Id (say X001) in table t2 is changed to 1, automatically status of table t1 for the Id X001 is set to 1, like below

[image]

Hope I am clear, Please help, Thanks in advance.

I have tried with this

update t1 set status=1 where id=(select id from t2 where status<>0 group by id,status)

but it updates status of t1 whenever it finds a status 1 in t2 for distinct id.
I want that the table should be updated only when all the values of status of t2 is set to 1 for each id

please help

Comment: You need a trigger on update? or you perform the update manually?

Comment: can you please provide me with the trigger syntax, I have not much idea on trigger

Answer (score 0):

You should create a view that joins both table to show the status.

If you try to update both tables every time the status changes you could get inconsistent tables. A view works like a table but you can do join and select operations to format your results.

More on views: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

Comment: actually i want a trigger implementation as joining will not solve my problem

Comment: You want to have inconsistent statuses that are only synced after T1 is updated?